# Test-Connection formatting returns blanks

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the Test-Connection command on a machine.  If I use

```
Test-Connection TESTMACHINE
```

it works fine and returns results in the Source, Destination, IPV4Address, IPV6Address, Bytes, and Time(ms) columns.  However, if I try and drill down the fields like so:

```
Test-Connection TESTMACHINE | Select-Object Destination, IPV4Address
```

it will only return the IPV4Address and the Destination column will be blank.

Is this an error with Powershell or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the actual object returned. The property holding the destination name seems to be actually called "Address".

So try:

```
Test-Connection TESTMACHINE | Select-Object Address, IPV4Address
```

regards
Arcass

Comment: To expand on what Arcass said, what you probably should have done is a `Test-Connection TESTMACHINE | Get-Member` and taken a look at what properties are available. Then you can see what you want to put in your `Select-Object`.

Comment: How would I go about checking that?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Since I was brought here due to a similar situation but mine was more related to how to call address down the pipeline. Probably forgetting a standard reserved call out method but for `(Test-Connection "TESTMACHINE").Address` how do you get that to work? I had to rename the column in my select from "Address" to "ComputerName" for it to work. I tried wrapping it in quotes like ."Address" but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the issue fully. My comment is about piping an object to `Get-Member` to see the available properties. Perhaps you should post a new question to properly ask what it is you need help with.